# Play a sound while a new image fades in then fades out as the sound ends (Object C)

Tags: ios, swfobject

I have been looking everywhere for this question but can't seem to find the answer. Right now I have an app that play a sound when tapped on the screen.

However, **I was hoping that I could make a new image to fade in as the sound is being played and then fade out as the sound end**. The sound is about 10s. All of this supposed to happen just with 1 tap.

I don't even know if this instance is feasible or if it makes sense as the flow seems a bit odd to me. It's almost like trying to play a short movie using trick around it.

What do you guys think? Please please please help me this is important and I'm still very new to Object-C

Thanks so much!

This is my ViewController.m, The image I want to fade and then fade out is called imageView.png

[please see a screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keb5b.png)

Answer (score 0):

In Objective-C, you can easily chain animations together. Assuming you have your image showing in a `UIImageView` named `imageView`:

```
imageView.alpha = 0.f;
...
[UIView animateWithDuration:5 animations:^{
    imageView.alpha = 1.f;
} completion:^{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:5 animations:^{
        imageView.alpha = 0.f;
    }];
}];
```

This assumes a 10 second sound, and that you want the image to fade in and out with equal portions of the duration. You'd probably want a better way to keep the time.

Comment: That's correct. And AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(...) is asynch, so you can start the sound before the above animations. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/SystemSoundServicesReference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/AudioServicesPlaySystemSound

Comment: Hi, the app is all about the sound and we will have a different sound for each app. I don't think it's applicable in this case as it's not a system sound. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @iamataptool: Please help me out, I'm not sure where to put that code in the ViewController.m. I created by UIImageView by dragging it from the User Interface Builder so I'm not sure where I should place this code. And will this happen on a tap? Pls bear with me as this is literally my first app ever.

Comment: If this is your first app, I would suggest following a resource to guide you through the development process the first time. It will save you a great deal of time. After you get the basics down, you will be able to expand upon them to create a more complex app. It's tempting to want to create something with no experience, but please trust me when I say it is a wise investment to learn the fundamentals first. I would suggest starting here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/1797/ios-tutorial-how-to-create-a-simple-iphone-app-part-1

Comment: hi man, don't get me wrong. I'm so down to learn from scratch and everything as that's how I learned everything else. I only ask for this instance because I know it could be such a quick fix as I already have the sound play on tap and everything, just this one transition is what's holding me back. This is also not for my own leisure but some pro-bono that I'm trying to help a friend out. Thanks for your insight though. @iamataptool

Comment: You can start the animation immediately after you begin playing the sound, i.e., on the next line. You might want to move all of that code into `-viewDidAppear:`, though